# Oracle query to count no of mondays......... sundays and total no of jobs on particular day in particular time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have   a table

```
JobID   Date_of_Completion  Region    day
1        23/05/2016          South    monday
2        23/05/2016           north   monday
3        23/05/2016            north  monday
4        23/05/2016            east   monday
5        22/05/2016          South    sunday
6        22/05/2016           north   sunday
7       22/05/2016            south sunday
8       22/05/2016            east  sunday
.
.
.
..
23        2/05/2016            north  monday
24        2/05/2016            east   monday
25        2/05/2016          South    monday
26        2/05/2016           north   monday
27       2/05/2016            south monday
28       2/05/2016            east  monday
```

desired output :
for last two months

```
Day           Region      countofjobsonparticularday          no of days
sunday         south            34               8 (no of sund forlast 2 months)
sunday         north            24               8 (no of sund forlast 2 months)
monday         south            74              9 (no of mon forlast 2 months)
tuesday        east            64               8 (no of tue forlast 2 months)
```

how to write a query? plz help me

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @aleksej  select distinct(dateofcompletion),  region,day from table. I am  just starter

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need something like this:

```
select Day, Region, count(1), count(distinct date_of_completion)
from your_table
where date_of_completion between add_months(sysdate, -2) and sysdate
group by Day, Region
```

This will count the number of jobs and the number of DISTINCT days on which job completed.
You should refine this, based on your need ( for example how you want to consider hours, minutes, ...,)

Comment: I believe `no of days` is meant to come from the calendar, rather than from the table.

Answer (score 0):

If - as I suspect - you mean the last column, `no of days`, is supposed to show the total number of Mondays, Tuesdays, etc. over the last two months (regardless of whether there were any jobs on some of the days), first create a (sub)query as below and then join to Aleksej's result on the `Day` column. Speaking of `Day`, it is an Oracle keyword; it is always best to avoid using Oracle keywords as table or column names. I use day_name below.

Result of query (can be used as subquery):

```
DAY_NAME                CT
--------------- ----------
monday                   9
thursday                 8
sunday                   9
saturday                 9
tuesday                  8
friday                   9
wednesday                8
```

I didn't order the results (not needed, if used for a join) and I used low-caps as the OP did. That is controlled by the format model (the middle argument to `to_char` in the query, below; if capitalized names, like Monday, are desired, change that from `'day'` to `'Day'`).

Query:

```
with x (day_name) as (
        select to_char(sysdate - level + 1, 'day', 'nls_date_language = American') 
        from   dual 
        connect by level <= sysdate - add_months(sysdate, -2) - 1
     )
select   day_name, count(*) as ct
from     x
group by day_name;
```

Note `'nls_date_language = American'` - it is always best to make that explicit than to rely on default parameters. (Without this third argument, someone else running this with German or Chinese date language wouldn't get the expected result for joining with the other table.) Also, the definition of "last two months" is fuzzy; I used all days between today (included) and two months ago, that is between March 24 and May 23, 2016. These are controlled by the two expressions containing `sysdate`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mathguy and@Aleksej

I tried this query it worked

select to_char(dayofcompletion,'DY') as day_name, count(1),count(distinct(trunc(dayofcompletion))) as noofdays
from tablename
where trunc(dayofcompletion)>= trunc(sysdate-60)and trunc(dayofcompletion)<=trunc(sysdate-1)
group by to_char(dayofcompletion,'DY')